# How to switch between integrated terminals in Visual Code?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, ubuntu

The documentation lists some of the shortcuts for using the integrated terminal: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf.

I've multiple integrated terminals open. Are there any shortcut for switching between these terminals, so that a mouse-click can be avoided?

[image]

Comment: read this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12054

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of switching between integrated terminal windows is not enabled by default in `Default Keybindings`. However, it can be enabled by adding the following lines to `keybindings.json`, thereby overwriting existing shortcuts:

```
   { "key": "ctrl+,",      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext" },
   { "key": "ctrl+.",      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious" }
```